# How can you both delete a line and append another with a one-liner sed command?

Tags: scripting, sed

I know how to do deletion and substitution with sed, but I'm having trouble using the append command with it. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
sed -i '' -e '/optima/d' file
```

This removes the correct line from the file (supposing it exists). However, I'd also like to add another line to the end of the file, and I can't use "echo something >> file" on a second line. I can't even use a second sed invocation.

What is the syntax for doing this?

Comment: Also worth looking at the sed answers on: http://superuser.com/q/590630/26006

Answer (score 4):

A better approach here is to print all but the line you want to drop and then append the last line. This works even if the line that you are removing is the last line, while Kent's approach doesn't work for this case.

```
sed -i -n -e '/optima/!p' -e '$asomething' file
```

Example:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n -e '/5/!p' -e '$asomething'
1
2
4
something
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd also like to add another line to the end of the file...

try this:

```
sed -i ''  '/optima/d; $a \something' file
```

example:

```
kent$ seq 20|sed '/3/d; $a \yourText'
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
yourText
```

Comment: When I try that statement, I get the following error:  **sed: 1: "/optima/d; $a \something** and on a second line  **": extra characters after \ at the end of a command** .

Comment: Yes, with single quotes. I was even careful to have the correct whitespace. If this matters, it's on OS X w/bash, but I can't imagine they have a screwed up sed implementation.

Comment: I've no experience with os x. you could try insert a space between `a` and `$`... or with `-e` but I don't know if it will help. not familiar with bsd sed... :( this worked under gnu sed

Comment: This doesn't work in the corner case when you are removing the last line. E.g., try `seq 20|sed '/20/d; $a \yourText'`. Any workaround for this?

Comment: For OS X, you must skip the line between ```$a\``` and ```yourText``` =>
```seq 20|sed '/3/d; $a\[SKIP THE LINE]
yourText'```